Django default connections.cursor() not parsing JSONB into DICT despite using PSYCOPG3
I am switching an old codebase from Django ~2 to Django 4.2.1. Along side this switch, I upgraded psycopg2 to psycopg (also known as psycopg3), but this switch has caused my cursor to incorrectly fetch rows from my PostgreSQL database.
I am receiving STR instead of DICT when selecting JSONB objects in my database
Important: When I use psycopg.connect directly, all of the behavior returns to what I expected. It is only when I am using the default django connection. from django.db import connection
Here I fetch some json objects and check the type.
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("select json_file from json_file") # These are of type jsonb
    for row in cursor.fetchall(): 
        type(row[1])

This usually returns dict but is now returning str
Here is my DATABASES variable in settings:
'default': {'NAME': 'postgres',
  'USER': 'postgres',
  'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
  'HOST': 'db',
  'PORT': 5432,
  'CONN_MAX_AGE': None,
  'CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS': False,
  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
}

Here is Django's Connection + Cursor
> connections['default'].connection
<psycopg.Connection [IDLE] (host=db database=postgres) at 0x...>

> connections['default'].connection.cursor()
<django.db.backends.postgresql.base.Cursor [no result] [IDLE] (host=db database=postgres) at 0x...>

Here is psycopg's Connection + Xursor
> psycopg.connect("...")
<psycopg.Connection [IDLE] (host=db database=postgres) at 0x...>

> psycopg.connect("...").cursor()
<psycopg.Cursor [no result] [IDLE] (host=db database=postgres) at 0x...>

In [54]: django_connection.cursor_factory
Out[54]: django.db.backends.postgresql.base.Cursor

In [55]: psycopg_connection.cursor_factory
Out[55]: psycopg.Cursor

